# Can I call a vacuum cleaner cleaner a vacuum cleaner?

Tags: adjectives, parts-of-speech, jokes, compound-words

**Can I call a vacuum cleaner cleaner a vacuum cleaner?**

This was written in a hallway. Can you help me dissect what's going on here, along with an appropriate response?

By dissect, I mean I'd like to identify what *types* of words we're dealing with here. Is "vacuum cleaner," as in the household appliance, a compound noun? If so, is the first word "vacuum" an adjective? What about the occupation of a "vacuum cleaner cleaner" - how would I classify these words? Also, does this sort of wordplay go by a specific name?

Comment: Why the downvote? There are plenty of questions about how Buffalo buffalo buffalo.

Comment: I've never heard of anyone working as a cleaner of vacuum cleaners.  Maybe such a thing exists in the industrial world.

Comment: If a 'vacuum cleaner cleaner' is a machine for cleaning vacuum cleaners, then the person who _cleans_ the vacuum cleaner cleaner would be a 'vacuum cleaner cleaner cleaner'.

Comment: The term for the playing with words exemplified by 'Buffalo x 8' is 'trivia'. Of course you can use 'vacuum cleaner cleaner', but it's obviously going to sound quirky.

Comment: To be PC they probably want to be known as Vacuum Sanitation Engineers.

Comment: Heck, you could easily have a *vacuum vacuum cleaner cleaner*.

Comment: @HotLicks Wouldn't that be a "vacuum cleaner vacuum cleaner"? It's academic to us anyway, because we rarely speak of a vacuum cleaner. We call them "Hoovers". Or if they are of the modern bagless type - "Dysons".

Comment: @WS2 - No, a Hoover is a type of drone.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm afraid [its been a vacuum cleaner since 1908](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hoover_Company) - and they are still called Hoovers in Britain, and have always been, whether they were made by Hoover or not. I shall always call them that especially if it offends Mr Dyson, who is a Brexiteer.

Comment: @WS2 - You've never heard of a Hoovercraft?

Comment: @HotLicks I've certainly heard of a "hovercraft". It was invented in my own county of Norfolk, UK in the 1950s by a man called Christopher Cockerill, using a cocoa tin (it is said). [It is a sea-going vessel which rides on a cushion of air, and has amphibious abilities. It was used in Britain for cross-channel car ferries for many years, but I think has largely been replaced with the ensuing development, the hydrofoil.](http://muaznaseer.blogspot.com/2015/12/hovercraft-and-hydrofoils-by-chris.html) UK and US military have made use of these vessels for their amphibious qualities.

Comment: @WS2 - Speaking as an enthusiastic and unrepentant Brexiteer, my family always called our vacuum cleaner, "The vac". I am the proud owner of a very efficient Dyson!

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica  Made in Singapore or Malaysia - I've no doubt. The most efficient one I've ever had was one with a bag which we bought about 40 years ago - and it is still going strong. I keep it in the garage and use it to vac the car. We've had a couple of the bagless variety but I've never found them much to shout about - and they have had far shorter lives.

Comment: @WS2 - I've have a Miele of a similar age. It's excellent but at the back of the cupboard now. The Dyson has never caused me any problems. It's efficient  and it doesn't have any dangly bits to trip over or baggy bits to drag around.

Answer (score 2):

A "vacuum cleaner" is often referred to simply as a "vacuum". So something that cleans a vacuum *could* be a vacuum "cleaner". But "vacuum cleaner" is also the name for the device you're cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

What you've described is grammatically correct either way, but one sounds awkward ("vacuum cleaner cleaner") and one is ambiguous ("vacuum cleaner").

A useful workaround here:  simply say "a cleaner of vacuums" (or "a cleaner of vacuum cleaners").  "Vacuum cleaner" is a fading usage, at least in my dialect of English (in Canada we are likely to just call it a "vacuum"), but enough use the compound that it is confusing to employ it for any other usage.